# Docker container - 403 No valid crumb

Tags: java, docker, http, jenkins, http-status-code-403

I have docker with 2 containers on my windows.

1 jenkins container and 1 custom container with a JAVA API Spring boot.

Both work well (Tested with Postman and etc).

After, I have installed docker on a CentOS 8 linux server and I have pull these 2 images and I have started both containers.
They start well but when I test my API with Postman, I have a http error: 403 No valid crumb was included in the request.

Concerning the jenkins container, it say it is offline and when I read jenkins logs, I have this same error.

I don't understand why on my CentOS server I have this problem and not on my windows.

I search solutions on the web but I don't found any helpful solution (or I didn't understand them).
I don't have good knowledge on network / server infrastructure so I need your help.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using Jenkins to spill and start the containers ??

Comment: No, I did that manually.